# I need to create pad on the copper zone like as shown on the picture in Orcad PCB Editor 16.6

Tags: pcb-design, orcad

I am noob in Orcad PCB Design, I need a solution for creating pad on top of the copper zone as you can saw on picture, i need to create pad like that. I am using Orcad 16.6. Kindly give me the answer

Thank you[[image: OLD PCB1]

Comment: It's just a series of track segments with varying widths, surely?

Comment: Put the editor in "Shape Edit" mode and add a new shape.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely you will create this using a copper pour function. You draw a shape, place the shape on the appropriate layer and attach to it a net name (the signal name of the track it is replacing). Then OrCAD will fill in the copper inside the shape. You can also use the copper-fill feature in OrCAD (if I remember the name properly).

The difference between pour and fill is how it handles through plated holes that are located within the shape and connected to the same net. A pour will apply thermal spokes whereas a fill will merge the pad of the through plated hole to the copper. It will also run across non-connected pads creating a short so be aware of the difference. The **pour** feature avoids connections that are illegal.

So you need to decide which you use to suit the connectivity of the pad you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just to compliment Andy aka

This is a combination of copper pour and also solder mask.

In KiCAD such area's are known as **filled zones** but they fulfil the same function - means to designate an area to be flooded  with copper

A filled zone on its own however will be covered with resist, if it is on one of the two outer layers.

[image]

In conjunction with the mask, the area will be exposed.

[image]

In conjunction with the paste/stencil layer, the area will be flooded with solder during reflow since this influences the stencil used for assembly

[image]